# (Java) want to return String value from a method

Tags: java, string, return

I need to return the return value type in String.

This is working:

```
   import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Score {
        public void Display(){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please enter your marks: ");
            int newPoint = input.nextInt();
            newPoint = calculateSc(newPoint);
            System.out.println(newPoint);
         }

       public static int calculateSc(int point) {
            if (point <= 100 && point >= 80) {
                return 1;
            }else if (point <= 79 && point >= 60) {
                return 2;
            }else if (point <= 59 && point >= 50) {
                return 3;
            }else if (point <= 49 && point >= 40) {
                return 4;
            }else if (point <= 39 && point >= 30) {
                return 5;
            }else {
                return -1;
           }
       }
   }
```

This is desired code(Showing error):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
        public class Score {
            public void Display(){
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter your marks: ");
                int newPoint = input.nextInt();
                newPoint = calculateSc(newPoint);
                System.out.println(newPoint);
            }
            public static String calculateSc(int point) {  
                if (point <= 100 && point >= 80) {
                     return "You got  A+";//String value
                }else if (point <= 79 && point >= 60) {
                     return "You got A";
                }else if (point <= 59 && point >= 50) {
                     return "You got  A-";
                }else if (point <= 49 && point >= 40) {
                     return "You got  B";
                }else if (point <= 39 && point >= 30) {
                     return "You got  C";
                }else {
                     return "You got F (failed";
                }
           }
       }
```

I think you all understand, what I want to do.If you have any proper solution please answer.But don't wanna change second String method calculateSc()

Comment: Just change the return type to `String`.

Comment: No, I do not know what do you mean. Please explain properly the observed versus actual behavior.

Comment: Your return type in the second example is `int` but your return values are `String`. Change either the values' type or the return type so they match. Also, `(point <= 60 && point >= 70)` can never be `true`.

Comment: then the problem was method return type `Integer`  @resueman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are returning String why are you putting return type to be int? Try learn more about methods and return types

```
public static String calculateSc(int point) { 
        if (point <= 100 && point >= 80) {
            return "You got A+";
        } else if (point <= 60 && point >= 70) {
            return  "You got A";
        } else {
            return "You got F (Failed)";
        }
    }
```

you cannot assign String value in int variable remember method returns String after change. So replace these two lines,

```
newPoint = calculateSc(newPoint); 
System.out.println(newPoint);
```

with only this,

```
System.out.println(calculateSc(newPoint));
```

Comment: Thanks for ur advice.Then the problem is input `int point` @jack jay

Comment: @MrRango I din't get you. problem in `int point`

Comment: required `int` found `java.lang.String` @jack jay

Comment: Can you tell us what are you passing in this method.

Comment: I want to create another method for input and print.Such as `Please enter your mark: ` after that I want to input mark after that I want to print those return value `You got A+` @jack jay

Comment: there is no problem with that but you should show the rest of your code. and where this `required int found java.lang.String` error is getting, in the function which wrote in answer.

Comment: `newPoint = calculateSc(newPoint); //required int found java.lang.String` this line what i need to change.Full code in the main question @jack jay

Comment: Kindly add some reason for downvote?

Comment: please don't get me wrong.I even don't capable of doing this.I need 15 reputations for voting.I have only 3! You can check my profile. @jack jay

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jack Jay.For your kind helping and explanation.@jack jay

Comment: @MrRango From next time onwards try to be more specific what you want to ask.

Comment: Yes, of course, i will try Jack Jay. @jack jay

Comment: `import javax.swing.*;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}` @jack jay

Comment: Can you explain it to me? `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();//this is a class 
            }
        });`@jack jay

Comment: [Try reading this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml), if then also you aren't able to understand, then lets move to chat discussion.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, you do not want to change the return method from int.

You cannot return a String in an int method but you can print it out using System.out.print or simply have a method calculate the grade and another method return the String depending on the grade.

Answer (score 0):

> public static **int** calculateSc(...

The **int** there means the function will return an int type.

In the working code, all of the return statements return **int**, integers.

In the not-working code, you are trying to return **String** instead: a sequence of characters, rather than an integer.

A function cannot return a type other than the type it's declared to return.